# 2 Apache / LAMP in Same Machine

Tags: apache, redhat

We had an apache installation in our server but with old version (php 5.4). We have then installed LAMP in another location with the latest versions (php 7.1).

Now after restarting the server, the apache is only starting from old conf file. How to make to start from new setup?

Comment: You have to install two lampps seprate like lampp5 and lampp7 in /opt/

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Step 1: find your apache location with command find / -name apachectl
Step 2: start the exact apache for example if your location is /username/lamp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf 
then use this command
/username/lamp/apache2/bin/apachectl start